# JSON API's in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to send post request from the client(now i am checking that through postman).I don't know how to accept the  data which is coming as JSON format and store that into table?.when i send the request, It shows

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in TopicsController#create
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your controller is expecting an auth token.

You can skip this for certain actions using:

`skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:action_name_goes_here]`

This is intended to prevent cross site request forgery, so be careful with it. The official docs are here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures.

Here's the important part:

> By default, Rails includes an unobtrusive scripting adapter, which
>   adds a header called X-CSRF-Token with the security token on every
>   non-GET Ajax call. Without this header, non-GET Ajax requests won't be
>   accepted by Rails. When using another library to make Ajax calls, it
>   is necessary to add the security token as a default header for Ajax
>   calls in your library. To get the token, have a look at  tag printed by <%=
>   csrf_meta_tags %> in your application view.